# Where can I find a good tutorial for installing bcache?

Tags: linux-kernel, cache, bcache

Question is updated. Now bcache is part of the standard OS compilation.

So it should be easy to install that now. I'll just order some SSD and some big HDD.

Where can I found it?

I found on the net and it's all too complicated.

http://bcache.evilpiepirate.org/ for example seems like the official page for bache. Yet nothing is found there. How to install? How to set up? Nothing

Some tutorial says that I have to make bcache, where can I download it? How do I download it?

Some says that I have to recompile kernel. Some tutorial doesn't mention that. Which one is right?

Nothing makes sense.

Okay there is git. Then what? What to do with git?

Comment: What is not real about this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good little tutorial at this location: http://atlas.evilpiepirate.org/git/linux-bcache.git/tree/Documentation/bcache.txt?h=bcache-dev (liked to from BCache's main website).

Take a look at the `Getting Started` and `ATTACHING` sections. If something specifically isn't clear, you should update your question and we could possibly help some more.

Comment: It says I have to make bcache, where can I download it? How do I download it?

Comment: @JimThio You can download it using git. See http://bcache.evilpiepirate.org/#Getting_bcache

Answer (score 3):

It will be a long walk through if you really need it.

`bcache` are kernel patch. Enhancement/feature that can be added to Linux kernel by patching the kernel source tree and compiling the kernel.

However it is still under testing and review, that's why it is not included in official kernel yet. Though [this blog](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTI3NDg) say it maybe soon. In the current state I would not recommend do it. Especially not on production server.

More over, putting in experimental kernel patches/features, kind of defeat the main purpose of using a distribution like CentOS/RedHat, for their stability.

Comment: So if I uses CentOs, can I uses bCache?